# Create paragraph in subthread to FlowDocument in main thread

Tags: c#, wpf, multithreading, richtextbox, paragraph

I´m creating a `Thread` to do some long run process and building a Paragraph that I shall show in a `RichTextBox`.

Normally this is simply done by:

```
Paragraph paragraph = new Paragraph();
paragraph.Inlines.Add(new TextBlock()
{
    Text = "Hello i´m som text",
        TextWrapping = TextWrapping.NoWrap
});
richtextbox.Document = new FlowDocument(paragraph);
```

(Works Fine)

But I want the Paragraph to be created in a thread and then added to the `RichTextBox` like:

```
Thread t = new Thread(new ThreadStart(CreateText));
t.Start();

private void CreateText()
{
    Paragraph paragraph = new Paragraph();
    paragraph.Inlines.Add(new TextBlock()
    {
        Text = "Hello i´m som text",
            TextWrapping = TextWrapping.NoWrap
    });
    Main.Dispatcher.Invoke(System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherPriority.Normal, new Action(() =>
    {
        richtextbox.Document = new FlowDocument(paragraph);
    }
}
```

My problem is that this will return Error:

> The calling thread cannot access this object because a different thread owns it. on richtextbox.Document = new FlowDocument(paragraph);

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2728896/the-calling-thread-cannot-access-this-object-because-a-different-thread-owns-it/2729040#2729040

Comment: sorry but cant see the connection....

Comment: The error line is pretty obvious, you're trying to change the content of a UI element through a thread that is not the current UI Thread. So you have to get the thread that has access on let that one update your control.

Comment: and if i do that, will my code take 1 minute and 30 seconds to process.... and the idea off a sub thread is gone, cause i nearly always process data to the paragraph that is used be UI thread.
I thought what the idea of a sub thread was to create the longtime process and return the result to the UI, but correct me if i´m wrong.

Comment: The only way to get your UI updates is to get the thread that handles the UI, so performance wise, there's no other option. You can always use a different thread to do all the work on and then call the UI thread, that's still a different case.

Comment: The Paragraph instance was created in a different thread and you trying to add it into richtextbox that was created in main UI thread.

Comment: yes cause it takes to long to let the UI Thread create the Paragraph it self..

Comment: Thanks Djerry, but still my main problem is, that the point in this thread is to create the Paragraph, cause it is a lot to process 3000 lines in a Paragraph, and takes way to long time to process as UI thread..
But maybe your right i will try to find a way and let the UI create the object.

Answer (score 0):

I already shared the solution to this problem as an answer to the similar question,
please refer to the [SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24626286) and [my blog post](http://turecki.net/node/20).
In terms of performance and lack of UI blocking if should fit your needs. If you have found another way of solving the problem since 2013, can you also share?